# Implementing 'ADD' command for a nano processor

Tags: hardware, fpga, boolean-logic

I'm not sure whether this is the correct stack exchange site for this question since this is mostly dealing with hardware level

I'm developing a nano processor. It's just for learning the architecture of a CPU so the development is done using logic gates and simulated on a BASYS2 board (FPGA).

Now that I'm developing the Instruction Decoder part, I'm confused in making the ADD / SUB actions
For LOAD I simply enabled the necessary register to store the literal defined in binary and send it to that registry
but for ADD, do we need to have 2 clock cycles to first ADD and then store the result or can we do it in just one cycle?

Thankx

Comment: FWIW, I think the most appropriate board for this question would be [Electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

You should only require 1 clock cycle, just like load, providing both operands are available, for example if your instruction was add literal to working register then the decoder would gate the working register output to one input of the adder, and the instruction bits containing the literal to the other input. The output of the adder would be routed to the destination, just the same as the load instruction.